# Laravel 5.2 Validation with column check

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a table that contains products for an organisation. The system will contain multiple organisations in a multi tenant way.

My `products` table has the following columns:

```
id   organisation_id   product_id  other_columns
```

I have created a request for `products` and I am now wanting to validate the input from the `create product` form. The requirement is for `product_id` to be unique for this `organisation_id`

The `rules()` method in my `request` is

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'part_number' => 'required|max:20|unique:products,part_number,'.$request->organisation_id.',organisation_id',

         'other_fields_here' => ...

    ];
}
```

The above does not work, so I have failed to understand the Laravel documentation. 
Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you want the tuple (organisation_id,part_number) to be unique. Try that:

```
// ... other rules
'part_number' => 'unique:products,part_number,NULL,id,organisation_id,'.$organisation_id,
// other rules ...
```

the options are: `unique:table,field,id_to_be_ignored,id_field_of_the_table,additional_where_conditions`

where additional where conditions are pairs to be compared equal, so in your case organisation_id, the field and $organisation_id, the value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was:

```
public function rules()
 {
     return [
         'part_number' => 'unique:products,part_number,NULL,id,organisation_id,' . $orgId),
```